# Java code works, but unsure if I have fulfilled the requirements (objects and classes)

Tags: java, class, object, methods, bluej

I got this homework requirement, and I've written a solution for it. But unsure if I got the answer right. 
Code works and compiles.

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Prs5o.jpg)

And this is my java file (2 file)

First is the primary file

```
public class Employee
{
String name;
int idNumber;
String department;
String position;

public Employee(String emName, int idNum, String depart, String pos)
{
    name = emName;
    idNumber = idNum;
    department= depart;
    position = pos;
}

public Employee(String emName, int idNum)
{
    name = emName;
    idNumber = idNum;
    department= "";
    position = "";
}

public Employee()
{
    name = "";
    idNumber = 0;
    department= "";
    position = "";
}

//set name
public void setName(String nameSet)
{
    name = nameSet;
}

//get name
public String getName()
{
    String nameGet = name;
    return nameGet;
}

//set idnum
public void setID(int idSet)
{
    idNumber = idSet;
}

//get idnum
public int getId()
{
    int idGet = idNumber;
    return idGet;
}

//
//set department
public void setDep(String depSet)
{
    department = depSet;
}

//get department
public String getDep()
{
    String depGet = department;
    return depGet;
}

//
//set position
public void setPos(String posSet)
{
    position = posSet;
}

//get position
public String getPos()
{
    String posGet = position;
    return posGet;
}

}
```

Second adds data and prints data

```
       public class Employee_test
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Employee employee1 = new Employee("Susan Meyers", 47899, "Accounting", "Vice President");
    Employee employee2 = new Employee("Mark Jones", 39119, "IT", "Programmer"); //use second with Mark
    //Employee employee2 = new Employee("Mark Jones", 39119);
    Employee employee3 = new Employee("Joy Rogers", 81774, "Manufacturing", "Engineer"); //use third with Joy
    //Employee employee3 = new Employee();

    System.out.println("Name           ID Number   Department     Position");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println(employee1.getName() + "   " + employee1.getId() +  "       " + employee1.getDep() + "     " + employee1.getPos());
    System.out.println(employee2.getName() + "     " + employee2.getId() +  "       " + employee2.getDep() + "             " + employee2.getPos());
    System.out.println(employee3.getName() + "     " + employee3.getId() +  "       " + employee3.getDep() + "  " + employee3.getPos());
    System.out.println("");
}

}
```

Here's the output when I run the employee_test file.

[Output terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3Piu.jpg)

What am I confused at.

Question says

```
Make sure you use all three constructors. Use the first constructor with Susan, the second with Mark and the third one with Joy.
```

How can the output be achieved if the question wants the 2nd employee to use a constructor that only have (name, id number) and third one has nothing ().
Thanks in advance.

Comment: By using the setName, setID, etc. functions after calling the constructor. They exist for a reason, and that is likely the purpose of the assignment

Comment: Basically they are wanting you use the `setter` methods with the 2nd and 3rd Employee Objects

Comment: @JacobH - so I should use the two constructors. Then use the setName, setID, setDep, and setPos to achieve results?

Comment: @Yellow_13 - refresh your browser - answer given below by Bohemian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setters to fill in the other data:

```
Employee employee1 = new Employee("Susan Meyers", 47899, "Accounting", "Vice President");

Employee employee2 = new Employee("Mark Jones", 39119);
employee2.setDep("IT");
employee2.setPos("Programmer");

Employee employee3 = new Employee();
employee3.setName("Joy Rogers");
employee3.setID(81774);
employee3.setDep("Manufacturing");
employee3.setPos("Engineer");
```

Note that from a design aspect, all fields should be `private`, and `ID` should also be `final`, since `ID` is not going to change once the employee is created. The `name` field could change if the person changes their name (marriage, witness protection, whatever) and the other fields could change from time to time.

Comment: Ok, I've changed the code to your suggestion. - But how do I set "ID" to final?

Comment: @Yellow_13 `private` is a field modifier, eg `private int ID`, but if you do that, you'll have to provide a value for ID at construction time, so you'll either have to delete the noargs constructor *or* generate an ID in that constructor.

Comment: I changed all the argument in employee.java to "private" - the program still works. And for ID to be final, I should create the 3 ID variable for each employee? (ex "private final int idNumber1;")?

Comment: @yellow no. Don't make the fields private *for this exercise* - it would change the question too much. Leave the employee class as it is. I just meant that in the real world they should be private.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for the suggestion.